# The characters I face in alipay

Tags: simplified-characters

大家好，
I wanted to know what does what is the exact meaning of 专区  in 5G专区，I saw it in alipay, I search in dictionary but it does not have any sense to me, can someone explain when I should use 专区。
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

专 in 专区 refers to 专用 (dedicated).

'5G 专区' means "dedicated area for 5G LTE connection"

5G LTE is the latest upgrade for cell phones connection speed (10 times faster than 4G LTE)

Alipay is keeping up with the latest technology. Currently, only a few areas in the world are equipped to provide the 5G LTE connection